# Attachment in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have a document with an attachment.The document is in edit mode but i want to restrict user to edit the attachment.User should be only able to open an attachment and should not be able to edit that attachment or Edit option should remain inactive.I am woking on client based application.If you have idea how to make Edit option inactive, then please share it with me.

Thanks Rupesh

Answer (score 1):

I have not done any notes thick client work in more than a few years, but one way would be to have 2 subforms with the same richtext field. One gets an editable rt-field, and the other gets a computed-when-composed (same field name).

Put the subform in the base form as a computed subform. Base the formula on role, so you either get an editable field or non-editable field based on who you are.

I was thinking you could do this with a controlled section as well, but it's been too long to recall for me. I know the subforms would work.